# virtuemart onafterConfirmorder , execute code after order

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

Is there any event like onafterConfirmorder in virtuemart ?
like in joomla onAfterRender,onBeforeRender events.
i want to execute code after order has been confirm .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you have to create a plugin for this concept.

First you need to find the `ORDER` section in Virtumart. The following model file contains all the order functionality.

```
ROOT_PATH\folder_name\administrator\components\com_virtuemart\models\order.php
```

In this file you have to find where the order has been completed. In that section once the order was completed you have to trigger this plugin process your functionality.

You can call any event of plugin which is defined in that plugin.

```
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$data       = array($argu1, $argu2);   // any number of arguments you want
return $dispatcher->trigger(onAfterRender, $data);
```

Then it will trigger the `onAfterRender` event in plugin which you created.

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );

/**
 * Example system plugin
 */
class plgSystemExample extends JPlugin
{
/**
* Constructor.
*
* @access protected
* @param object $subject The object to observe
* @param array   $config  An array that holds the plugin configuration
* @since 1.0
*/
public function __construct( &$subject, $config )
{
parent::__construct( $subject, $config );

// Do some extra initialisation in this constructor if required
}
/**
* Do something onAfterRender
*/
function onAfterRender()
{
}
}
```

Like this you have to create your plugin..

All the best....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the path is different in Joomla 2 or 3?
In Joomla 1.5 there is no path like:

> ROOT_PATH\folder_name\administrator\components\com_virtuemart\models\order.php

Only the following path exists:

> ROOT_PATH\folder_name\administrator\components\com_virtuemart\classes\ps_order.php